# Filter on partial kernel name with Nsight Compute

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nsight-compute

I am trying to filter on a partial name when profiling kernels in my program using NVIDIA Nsight Compute 2021.2.1. I believe it has worked before to use substrings or regex to match more than one kernel. However when I try it now I do not get any results unless I either leave the field blank or write the full name.[image].

How do I accomplish this through the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See changelog for version 2021.1:

> - --kernel-regex and --kernel-regex-base options are deprecated and replaced by --kernel-name and --kernel-name-base, respectively.
> - All options which support regex need to provide regex: as a prefix before an argument to match per the regex, e.g  regex:expression

So you need to write `regex:almostFullkernelnam` in the field.

https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-compute-2021_1-new-features